# Whats the difference between using assigned variables and straight access

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, equals, dataview

Considering below what are benefits, uses or gain of each and why do you think so? other than short way to access the data. btw is there a way to use DataView in `using (Resource){//Code}` format.

```
DataTable dtUsers = UsersRepository.GetAllUsers();
Users.Name = dtUsers.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
Users.Address = dtUsers.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
...
...
...
```

and

```
DataView dvUsers = UsersRepository.GetAllUsers().DefaultView;

Users.Name = dvUsers[0]["Name"].ToString();
Users.Address = dvUsers[0]["Address"].ToString();
...
...
...
```

Comment: it depends what will you do next with dtUsers which will allow you more flexibility out of the box than dvUsers

Comment: @eugene But the `DataView` does have `ToTable` method to get back the table right? also the above has no performance gain etc??

Comment: ToTable() method is exactly what i've meant by not being "out of the box". You question depends on what would you do next with Dataview or Datatable object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataView is there to be able to perform sorting, filtering, searching, editing, and navigation ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx)) without altering the data in the datatable itself. 
One of the biggest functionality thereof is for databinding to grid like controls so that you can control what data is displayed and how (Other than filtering/sorting it on sql level).

Another thing to note is that you can have multiple data views from one datatable, i.e. the one grid will display all the rows where the it's a male and the other grid will display all the females for instance.

Why would you want to use a using statement on a dataview? The whole reasoning behind a using statement is to dispose and close the object and release all resources after the code block is complete. That said, the only requirement to be able to use it in a using statement is it must implement IDisposable, which DataView does.

**EDIT**
In your code example though, there should be no difference except for a slight performance gain when you don't use DataView because it creates an index, so essentially using the dataview is an unneccessary extra step if you aren't going to use it's functionality

Comment: @TBohnen how is this going to help me answer above question. I never asked for `uses of DataView` or is the question framed wrongly by me

Comment: As I can gather from the question you wan't to know why would you rather use UsersRepository.GetAllUsers().DefaultView which returns a DataView instead of UsersRepository.GetAllUsers() which returns a DataTable. This explains why you whould use dataview instead of just normal datatable. In your code example though, there should be no difference, so essentially using the dataview is an unneccessary extra step

Comment: Also, when you create a DataView it creates an index of the data, which obviously have a performance impact, whether the DefaultView is created when the DataTable is created or whether it is created when you first call the get, I don't know, but it would be easy to find out with reflector

Comment: Cool, did it give you an answer though? :-)